# Probability Theory and distribution

Tags: probability

I need to solve the following problem:

There's a cafetria with multiple foods.Every time you roll a dice you're given a different food.
There's a 27/1024 probability that the food will be pizza, and 9.3/1024 probability that it'll be hamburger.

The question asks how many times the dice has to be rolled in order to create a substiantially distinguish the number of pizzas from the number of hamburgers. Take the distinguishing factor to be 1.5.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you define what the distinguishing factor means, precisely? Does it mean
$$
\frac{\text{number of pizzas}}{\text{number of hamburgers}} \geq 1.5
$$?

Comment: This is exactly what I mean

Comment: One obvious question is, what happens if the first roll results in a pizza? Then you have 1 divided by 0 ...